# Standard error of random intercepts

Tags: mixed-model

I am trying to figure out generally speaking how the standard errors for an individual estimated random intercept can be computed given the group-level and the individual-level variances.

The model would be the random intercept model $y_i=\alpha_{j[i]}+\beta x_i + \epsilon_{ij}$ where $i$ is an individual measurement in group $j$.

Given $\hat{\sigma}_{\epsilon}^2$ and $\hat{\sigma}_{\alpha}^2$, I would expect the standard error of an individual $\alpha_j$ estimate to be related to the number of individuals $n_j$ in the group, something like $\sqrt{\frac{\hat{\sigma}_{\epsilon}^2}{n_j}}$ but I am not getting the correct standard errors (I am trying to reproduce what is on pg. 261 of Gelman & Hill).

Comment: Looking [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2016q4/025230.html) they seem to take the square root of the posterior variance, as also implemented in `arm::se.ranef`. I can't shed much light on the theory though..

Comment: @PBulls I saw that too. In the book they give the sample sizes of a few specific groups along with the variance estimates, and I thought it should be enough to compute the standard errors directly